# At what temperature I should install another cooler for the processor?

Tags: cpu, temperature, core

I have a Intel dual core processor, code name Ivy Bridge, frequency ~3GHz, max TDP is 55.0W. I use *Core Temp* to monitor the temperature while all cores are at nearly 100% load. The temperature readings are:

> **Core #0**
>
> > Min: 53 °C
> >     Max: 59 °C
>
> **Core #1**
>
> > Min: 54 °C
> >     Max: 61°C

Are the cores *hot*, *very hot* or *too hot*? At what temperature I should install another cooler?

Comment: You can look up your cpu model specifications on the intel website. The maximum acceptible temperature is called Tcase in their terms, so look for that. For example, my CPU's Tcase is 60 C, but even when it reaches 70 C, it is still working. If the CPU's temperature is too high, the computer will shutdown, but no damage will be dealt to CPU.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, your cores aren't very hot or too hot. I guess they're just hot at max load. CPU nowadays have a TJmax at 105 C and it shuts down itself at this point. I have an i5 4670k (with Cooler Master heat sink) and at max load the temperatures are around 60 C (my ambient temperatures are between 25 - 30 C).